# Ant Build passes but Sonar build fails!

Tags: ant, hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Sonar new version with Ant build connectint to Hudson.

I get following error in the console.

The build gets success but at the end it gives a failure on maven! i am only using Sonar-Ant Target. I am not doing anything with pom.

> [sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Database optimization done: 421 ms BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL Total time: 49 seconds [workspace] $ mvn.bat -f
>   "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\hegdera.hudson\jobs\ZOOR2\workspace\pom.xml" -e -B
>   sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:8001
>   + Error stacktraces are turned on. [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'sonar'. [INFO]
>   Ignoring available plugin update: 2.0-beta-2 as it requires Maven
>   version 3.0 [INFO] Ignoring available plugin update: 2.0-beta-1 as it
>   requires Maven version 3.0 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Maven Default Project [INFO]    task-segment:
>   [sonar:sonar] (aggregator-style) [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] BUILD ERROR [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Cannot execute mojo: sonar. It requires a project with an
>   existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one. [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Trace org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Cannot execute mojo: sonar. It requires a project with an existing
>   pom.xml, but the build is not using one.  at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)     at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)  at
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375) Caused
>   by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot execute
>   mojo: sonar. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the
>   build is not using one.   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:414)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>     ... 17 more [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: < 1 second [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 15 17:37:18
>   GMT+05:30 2011 [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Finished: FAILURE

Anyone help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! its done by Sonar Hudson Plugin! its always looking for Maven Pom.xml!

Comment: You made no mention of the Hudson plugin.... Yeah, prior to the introduction of the Sonar ANT task (version 2.6) projects had to create a dummy POM file in order to integrate with Sonar. Far as I know the Hudson plug-in dates back to that period..... My recommendation is to run Sonar analysis from within an ANT job.

Answer (score 0):

The build failure is being thrown because Maven cannot file a POM file....... Why are you running Maven, when you are trying to use the ANT Sonar task?

The new functionality (introduced by Sonar 2.6) enables you to run Sonar analysis from ANT as follows:

```
$ ant sonar
```

This of course assumes that you have added a new target to your `build.xml` called "sonar". For examples of this I recommend the Sonar ANT task [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task):

Comment: I am running Ant only.  I do run ant sonar. i have configured everything. when i run it do create the report in Sonar website in build i see build failed.

Comment: Sorry that does not match your command trace above. You are clearly running the **mvn.bat** command, which throws an error reporting no "pom.xml" file